# Grantor does not have GRANT permission

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012, ssms-addin

I have a gitlab user and a role assigned to it, now the gitlab user needs extra  grant permissions.

I am executing the following sentence. [ssms 2012]

```
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE to xxx;
```

**ERROR:**

Grantor does not have GRANT permission

What is the permission i should give to gitlab user so that it can give grant permissions to another user.

I have also tried this but same error

```
grant view server state to xxx with grant option
```

please tell me as a command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grantor does not have GRANT permission - issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554578/grantor-does-not-have-grant-permission-issue)

Comment: Look into the `WITH GRANT` option.

Comment: i did grant view server state to xx with grant option
same grantor error

Comment: Please post everything you have already tried in the question so people don't waste time suggesting things you have already ruled out.

Comment: I think you need to login to SSMS with a user that has higher permissions than what you are currently logging in as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear - the account that you are using to run the script does not have WITH GRANT permission and therefore it cannot give it to someone else. Check with your DBA.